# MySQL Unicode Sinhala data to DOMPDF

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

I have a MySQL table named as "revenue" that is included data in Unicode Sinhala fonts. Now I want to create a PDF output from that data using DOMPDF. I used the following code.

```
include_once '../dompdf_config.inc.php';

mysql_connect('localhost',"iacc","123");
mysql_select_db("iacc");

$result=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM revenue"));

$value=  mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$date=date("Y/m/d");

$html = '
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: FM-Malithi;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: url(../font/FM-Malithi.ttf) format("true-type");
    }
    </style>
  </head>

<body>

  <table  border = "3" >
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FFCCFF" width="8%" class="fs" scope="col">කාර්යාලය</td>
<td bgcolor="#FFCCFF" width="8%" class="fs" scope="col">මුදල</td>

  </tr>

    <tr>


  <td><input type="text" name="office" value="'.$value['office'].'" style="font-family: FM-Malithi, sans-serif;" /></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="amount" value="'.$value['amount'].'" style="font-family: FM-Malithi, sans-serif;" /></td>  
      </tr>



      </table>
  </body>
  </html>
';
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html,'UTF-8');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("dompdf_out.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));
```

2. But it returns ?????? for Unicode sinhala fields. I can not understand what I am going wrong. Can anyone help me. Tnx.

Answer (score 1):

**utf8 turning into '?????'**

What probably happened:

- you had utf8-encoded data (good)
- `SET NAMES latin1` was in effect (default, but wrong)
- the column was declared `CHARACTER SET latin1` (default, but wrong)

utf8 needs to be established in about 4 places.

- The column(s) in the database -- Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to verify that they are explicitly set to utf8, or defaulted from the table definition.  (It is not enough to change the database *default*.)
- The connection between the client and the server.  See `SET NAMES utf8`.
- The bytes you have.  (This is probably the case.)
- If you are displaying the text in a web page, check the `<meta>` tag.

Do not use the `mysql_` interface; use `mysqli_`.

(I don't know DOMPDF; there may be settings there.)

If `මුදල` shows as `à¶¸à·”à¶¯à¶½`, then you will have "Mojibake".
The HEX in the table should be `E0B6B8E0B794E0B6AFE0B6BD`.